# Is piracy stealing?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu alaikum brother, I'm a huge movie addict. I know watching movies is a sin. But I was wondering if downloading the pirated movie,  will that be considered as stealing??? (Humble request -Please try to answer with valid Hadith, not just a blind shot)

Comment: Blind shot: are you asking about downloading a movie, using *tools* to avoid paying for it, or are you asking for piracy?

Answer (score 0):

Wa aleikum al-salam, So I will give you things and you can see yourself.

**If "Piracy" was on a thing that is sort of (trading, selling, etc.) and people does not get it except with buying.**

then what is the difference between it and usual selling?

-Selling Fruits, Vegetables, Etc.

-Selling Technology.

-Selling Services.

isnt that a thing that people work hard to do it, and Intend to make money from?

Any of that, taking it without giving money to the seller is annoying and is not a good thing to do, it is cheating and I think you agree with me.

in addition of cheating on the seller, you may also make some people (sad, mad, angry, etc.) for putting money on this while they can get it free.

There are some Hadiths that talks about cheating but am afraid to miss-place it in this situation.

Just think yourself of what I said, despite of most of the movies are bad, as a good muslim tries to do good things and avoid as much as he can bad sins.

Thank you, I hope I answered.

And this is the hadith that talks about Cheating:

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "He who takes up arms against us is none of us; and he who cheats us is none of us."

[Muslim].

Another narration of Muslim is: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) happened to pass by a heap of corn. He thrust his hand in that (heap) and his fingers felt wetness. He said to the owner of that heap of corn, "What is this?" He replied: "O Messenger of Allah! These have been drenched by rainfall." He remarked, "Why did you not place this (the drenched part of the heap) over the corn so that people might see it? He who deceives is not of us."

وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏"‏ من حمل علينا السلاح، فليس منا، ومن غشنا، فليس منا‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه مسلم‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
وفي رواية له أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم مر على صبرة طعام، فأدخل يده فيها، فنالت أصابعه بللا، فقال‏:‏ ‏"‏ ما هذا ياصاحب الطعام‏؟‏‏"‏ قال أصابته السماء يارسول الله، قال‏:‏ ‏"‏ أفلا جعلته فوق الطعام حتى يراه الناس‏!‏ من غشنا فليس منا‏"‏‏.‏

ٌRefrence:https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin/17/69